# Warning: require_once error occurs

Tags: php, codeigniter, opencart

When i tried to download my opencart website from remote server and installed it on local server got this error please help me to over come this ??

> Warning: require_once(/home/healthisallc/public_html/healthisall.co.in/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\healthisall\index.php on line 26

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/healthisallc/public_html/healthisall.co.in/system/startup.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\healthisall\index.php on line 26

Comment: You Just have a full path in your index.php, the website was written most likely on Linux system, and you wanted to copy it on windows, you should change all your absolute paths into relatives ones.

Comment: Well, this mean the file `/home/healthisallc/public_html/healthisall.co.in/system/startup.php` cannot be found on your system. If you've copied everything from a linux-server to your Windows computer, it's normal pathes are broken.

Comment: Yeah Absolutely MR.D4V1D It has been downloaded from Linux VPS server. What i have to do for proper working ?

Comment: I've added an answer, please consider reviewing it and accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've transfered everything from a `Linux`-server to your `Windows`-computer. As the path in the include in an absolute Unix path (starts with a `/`), Windows can't recognize them and therefore cannot find the proper file.

I suggest you replace them by relative paths.

Like so:

```
require_once '/home/healthisallc/public_html/healthisall.co.in/system/startup.php';
```

becomes:

```
require_once 'system/startup.php';
```

This will make PHP looking for the file `startup.php` under the sub-folder `system` in the folder where the script including it is.

You can also [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to list all the folders you want PHP to look into when you include files.